# Is there an R function to split a row into three different rows based on the values in a column?

Tags: r, split

I have a data frame that was created from a software that populated my data with SNP ID's based on chromosome/position. Some chromosome/positions have more than one SNP ID associated with them, which outputted like row 35. Is there a way in R Studio to split ones that are like row 35 into 3 separate rows, where it would look like:

22:16490252:CT:C rs1175903481 22 22:16490252:CT:C;rs1175903481;rs541536337;rs763066770
...

22:16490252:CT:C rs541536337 22 22:16490252:CT:C;rs1175903481;rs541536337;rs763066770

22:16490252:CT:C rs763066770 22 22:16490252:CT:C;rs1175903481;rs541536337;rs763066770

Essentially every other column needs to be the same for the three SNPs, but instead of all being in the same row, they need to be separated.

Attached [Data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzyB6.png) is a sample of the data frame.

Comment: `separate_rows()` from `tidyr` might help you here.

Comment: Attach the data as text not as image

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would likely depend on what you need to do next, but columns 3:5 appear redundant. `unlist(strsplit('rs1175903481;rs541536337;rs763066770', ';'))
[1] "rs1175903481" "rs541536337"  "rs763066770"` are your three associated SNPs that could be assigned to new SNP1, SNP2 columns. `dput(my_lots_of_chromosomes[30:40,]` and copy `structure(...)` above would serve you better than the picture.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

library(stringr)
```

If SNP names `(rs1175903481;rs541536337;rs763066770)` are in column `V2` (for example) then you could do something like this:

```
splitSNP <- df %>% 
  mutate(V2 = strsplit(as.character(V2), ";")) %>% unnest(V2)
```

That should split the row into three new rows, with the same information in all of the columns but only one SNP name.